# How to execute a function from the value of a map object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to be able to execute a function which is saved as a value on Map object by referencing the key. For example:

```
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set("myKey", function(argument) {
    console.log(argument);
});

let value = myMap.get("myKey");
console.log(value);
```

The function is output to the console but I can't figure out how to actually execute the function.

I tried `let test = new Function(value)` but got the error message "Function statements require a function name"

Comment: Put parentheses after a function to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the function with parentheses:

```js
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set("myKey", function(argument) {
    console.log(argument);
});

let value = myMap.get("myKey");
value('Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 0):

As `get` method of `myMap` will give you the `function`, You just have to invoke it as

```
myMap.get("myKey")("Hello World!")
```

```js
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set("myKey", function (argument) {
  console.log(argument);
});

let value = myMap.get("myKey")("Hello World!");
```